# Error: Unable to access jarfile when I launch a process builder command

Tags: java, executable-jar, processbuilder

I build one program in Java with a main into a jarfile and I want to executable an other. The second program is also a jarfile.

To execute the second program, I use a process builder to execute the second jarfile with these arguments. But i didn't worked and I have this message :

Error: Unable to access jarfile path/second_program.jar

In first, I think its the path was wrong. But, I have execute the second jarfile in a terminal on windows and on linux whitout any problem.

```java
//IN THE FIRST PROGRAM
                Process process = null;
                List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (server.equals("TEST_linux")) {
                    commands.add("/bin/java");
                    commands.add("-jar");
                    commands.add("/mnt/c/Users/second_program.jar");
                    commands.add("param1");
                    commands.add("param2");
                } else {
                    commands.add("java");
                    commands.add("-jar");
                    commands.add("C:/Users/second_program.jar");
                    commands.add("param1");
                    commands.add("param2");                    
                }
                System.out.println(commands);
                //Execution de la commande externe
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
                System.out.println(pb.directory());
                pb.directory(new File(localFolder));
                System.out.println(pb.directory());

                pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
                process = pb.start();
                StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line = null, previous = null;

                file_generated_by_second_program = output_folder + "/" + panel + "/file_generated_by_second_program.txt";

                myFile = new File(file_generated_by_second_program);
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile, true));
                System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

All of the rest of the first program is executing perfectly. I use the first program which generated arguments to execute the second program which generate a file. This file is used after in the first program...
I can't launch the second program separatly...

Any ideas ?

UPDATE :

Here, these errors :

```java
//Windows before suggestions :
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:/Users/second_program.jar

//Windows after suggestions : 
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\second_program.jar

//Linux :
Error: Unable to access jarfile "/mnt/c/Users/second_program.jar"

System.out.println(br.readLine()); //==> this command doesn't execute too!
```

After the last row of my code, I create differents variables and these variables existing and there are no null. So for me, the problem is limited to the extract of my code...

SOLVED : I had an error in path...sorry

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You need to be more precise, when asking a question. Please, add full source code and full error. What is the value localFolder?

Comment: localFolder = "/mnt/c/Users" for Linux or "C:/Users/" for Windows

Full error is only : Error: Unable to access jarfile "path of second program. jar"

Answer (score 0):

This is related to different path separator characters:

- Windows is using "\"
- Linux is using "/"

Usually, following problem can be solved by using `File.separator` property, which will return the right character basing on OS that you are running. However, i can see that you are most likely using WSL, so it might not work in this case and you would have to hard-code this.

Summing up, you need to fix path to jar for Windows and differentiate output paths for both OS.

Comment: For Windows, I tried to modify the path with \...no change

For Linux, the path is correct (I used /) but I have the same error that Windows.